# Flutter iOS build suddenly says "The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined."

Tags: ios, flutter

All of a sudden my flutter app does not install on iOS. It has been working and building for a long time, and then all of a sudden I get this error...

```
Unable to install /Users/me/src/myapp/client/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on F0FDB4EA-7E61-49D5-A39F-BA1C10D0CFA4. This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl install F0FDB4EA-7E61-49D5-A39F-BA1C10D0CFA4 /Users/me/src/myapp/client/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

My info.plist definitely exists and has the bundle identifier specified as....

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```